# Does C# automatically initialize variables

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me if C# automatically initializes variables?  If so, what are the default values?

Comment: No, and you can easily demonstrate this in a few lines of code.

Comment: read up on "automatic properties" and "value types" in c#

Comment: Actually it does initialize member variables of a class

Comment: [First response in googleing your exact question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952503/c-sharp-variable-initialization-question)

Comment: look at `default` keyword

Comment: Check out MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/83fhsxwc.aspx

Comment: Variables aren't automatically initialized, but the fields are?

Comment: Search the web for "C# variable initialization site:msdn.com" and you [will be amazed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/08/490248.aspx).

Comment: not true @ScottChamberlain - it will only initialise the type if it is automatic property OR you declare the member i.e. private int = -1; etc if you just declared private int variable; it is not initialised it just has the space allocated for it (i.e. it would be null reference)

Comment: @PaulSullivan [ideone disagrees with you](http://ideone.com/zFTk5j) Member variables are initialized as `private T foo = default(T)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare something inline it will not

```
int Foo()
{
    int bar; //Bar is not initlized, this code will not compile
    bar =  bar + 1;
    return bar;
}
```

However if you declare inside a class it will have a default value equal to `default(type)`

```
class Baz
{
   int bar;

   int Foo()
   {
        bar =  bar + 1;
        return bar; //default(int) is 0 so this returns "1"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

c# has no default value for variables if the variable scope is a method ... if the scope is at least field, the default value will be `default(YourType)` ... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx